# Can someone help me identify some characters?

Tags: writing-identification

I have been playing Dai Gyakuten Saiban 2 with assistance from a script for the main game, but I am completely lost in (what I think is) the DLC menu and some unidentified characters popped up. I got 夕イトル画-に戻--す。 so far, with - being  characters I haven't gotten yet. The first one looks like a 3x3 grid with a small T  on top, the third is a backwards C with a line coming up from the top, and the third is a T with two top lines and a swirly bottom. Could someone help me by letting me know what the characters are?

Comment: Not only is this kind of question off topic, but you also fail to produce an image of what you want identified (although I know what you're looking for) . Please take it up in the chat room instead.

Comment: I don’t understand why it’d be off topic, is kanji identifying  not allowed as questions?

Also, he’s a new user, why are you so curt in your reply?

Comment: After verification, there is mention of:
> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.
Learning how to participate in our community can be hard. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.

Comment: Maybe you could try the handwriting recognition tool on Google Translate https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/98610779_2979629815478215_3625353887071862784_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&_nc_sid=8024bb&_nc_ohc=MDVazrrEnmYAX9Cs1kt&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=a872a840b1e2a5d6a89292a68b95baec&oe=5EE9B3FB

Comment: @Etienne, Yes, character recognition is off-topic here, I'm afraid. Please see our [Help Center](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one must be　面　as part of 画面.  I'm pretty sure the whole this is "Return to the title screen"

Comment: That sounds right, as there is only one text box and it boots you back to the menu